# Getting WebElement by Text using XPath in Selenium test

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I would like to find any WebElement based on text using XPath.

WebElement that I am interested to find,

[image: WebElement that I am interested in]

Its HTML,

[image: Its CSS]

Basically my WebElement that I am trying to retrieve by Text contains an input element.

I currently use,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[normalize-space(text()) = 'Own Hotel']"));
```

which does not find the WebElement above, but it usually works to retrieve all other web elements.

Even,

```
By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Own Hotel')]")
```

did not give me any results. Although I am interested in exact text match.

I am looking for a way to find web element by text immaterial of the elements that are present inside the web element. If text matches, it should return the WebElement.

Thanks!

Comment: No iframes on page. Throws `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: It is not a wait issue. I tested this xpath on chrome when the page was loaded, it does not find the element. Hence my xpath is not correct for this case. I need alternative xapth.

Comment: Please post the HTML code as text instead of a picture. At some future point the picture will no longer be available and this question won't be as helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems text is wrapped inside a label and not input. Try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[text()[normalize-space() = 'Own Hotel']]"));
```

There is nice explanation about this xpath pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819575/why-normalize-spacetext-ignores-internal-nodes-when-selecting-by-text)

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML below:

[image: HTML]

The *innerText* **Own Hotel** within the `<input>` node contains a lot of white-space characters in the beginning as well at the end. Due to the presence of these leading and trailing white-space characters you can't use the location path [`text()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev) as:

> `text()` selects all text node children of the context node

---

As an alternative, you need to use the [String Function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-String-Functions) `string normalize-space(string?)` as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[normalize-space()='Own Hotel']"));
```

---

However, it would a better idea to make your search a bit more granular adding the *tagName* and preferably an unque attribute as follows:

- Using *tagName* and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[normalize-space()='Own Hotel']"));
  ```
- Using *tagName*,  and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='ownHotel' and normalize-space()='Own Hotel']"));
  ```

---

### References

you can find a couple of relevant discussions using *normalize-space()* in:

- [How to click on a link with trailing white-space characters on a web page using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53930154/how-to-click-on-a-link-with-trailing-white-space-characters-on-a-web-page-using/53930289#53930289)
- [How to locate and click the element when the innerText contains leading and trailing white-space characters using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54080731/how-to-locate-and-click-the-element-when-the-innertext-contains-leading-and-trai/54089730#54089730)
- [How to click on the button when the textContext contains leading and trailing white-space characters using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053154/how-to-click-on-the-button-when-the-textcontext-contains-leading-and-trailing-wh/54053552#54053552)