# How to click on a link with trailing white-space characters on a web page?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There are links like this on a web page:

- Overview
- General Settings
- AR Server Settings
- Cache Settings
- Report Settings
- Web Service Settings
- Log Settings
- Change Password

I am writing an automation script in selenium under Java eclipse and want to click on Cache Settings option. Can some one help? I know this would be simple, but i am a newbie in this world.i am able to automate previous steps til coming to this web page and now stuck in clicking Cache settings.

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="textMainNav">Cache Settings </div> 
<div class="textMainNav">Report Settings </div>
```

I have tried few things but none working.

Comment: are you using XPATH?

Comment: all these elemets are links? and straightway displayed on page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the links you can use either of the following solutons:

- Click on `Overview`:

  - *xpath*:

    ```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='textMainNav' and normalize-space()='Overview']")).click();
    ```

Comment: can you elaborate on `normalize-space()`? thanks! (I just use `text()=`)

Comment: `normalize-space()` method is used to trim the spaces. if there are space before or after your string then `text()` method won't work. alternatively, for partial match you can use `contains()` method  e.g. `//div[@class='textMainNav'][contains(.,'Overview')]`

Comment: @NarendraR Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Hello Debanjan this is correct ..Thanks for your response. Appreciate it.