# How to click on the button when the textContext contains leading and trailing white-space characters?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on the following button using Selenium with python:

```
<button type="submit" tabindex="4" id="sbmt" name="_eventId_proceed">
          Einloggen
</button>
```

This is just a simple button which looks like this:

[image]

Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('sbmt').click()
```

This results in the following exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
Element <button id="sbmt" name="_eventId_proceed" type="submit">
could not be scrolledinto view
```

So, I tried scrolling to the element using `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_elements_by_id('sbmt')[1]).perform()` before clicking the button.

(Accessing the second element with `[1]` because the first would result in `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: rect is undefined` exception.).

Then I used

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
submit_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'sbmt')))
```

in order to wait for the button to be clickable. None of this helped.

I also used `driver.find_element_by_xpath` and others, I tested it with Firefox and Chrome.

How can I click on the button without getting an exception?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke `click()` on the element you need to first use *WebDriverWait* with `expected_conditions` for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='sbmt' and normalize-space()='Einloggen']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: why introduce a complex XPATH when you can just use `By.ID` with the id directly?

Comment: the OP already stated he tried essentially this same solution.. why did this help?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Going by the attributes of the `<button>` element of _submit_ type it is pretty much apparent that there are multiple elements with _id_ attribute as `sbmt`. In these cases using `By.ID` may not help OP. So I decided to club up the `innerText`. Hence the XPATH.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg OP's trials involved `By.ID` but there wasn't any trials including the `innerText` which seems to be the solution to OP's question.

Comment: might be nice to explain that in your answer

Comment: Well, it's obvious the culprit is there are 2 buttons, and the real solution here was just going by the element's text. Thus waiting - to be clickable, to appear, or whatever - is unnecessary, and only adds complexity and execution time.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg it helped because it showed me how to use the `By.XPATH` correctly. I tried using it but I specified it in the wrong way

Comment: Btw I figured out a much simpler way to solve my problem, which I should have tried before asking the question: The `sbmt` button was part of a name and password input field, so I just used `Keys.ENTER` instead.