# How to locate and click the element when the innerText contains leading and trailing white-space characters using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to locate (and click) the "Reoni" element, but I do not know what function to use it for

I tried with

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("oe_menu_leaf")
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("oe_menu_text")
```

but then selenium raise an error element cant be located,
and I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Reoni")
```

This is the element I want to locate:

```
<a href="/web#menu_id=86&amp;action=99" class="oe_menu_leaf" data-menu="86" data-action-model="ir.actions.act_window" data-action-id="99">
    <span class="oe_menu_text">
    Reoni
    </span>
</a>
```

and full html:

[image: html]

If I was not clear enough or if you needed my code, please let me know.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I see "collapse" in some of the other class names.  Is this a menu item that doesn't appear until you hover or click over the same menu with the mouse?  If so, that could explain why Selenium doesn't "see" it.

Comment: no, this item is all the time there @BillM.

Comment: This is a generic web code (html) from Odoo
i have xml file with which I added "Reoni" item, but it will not be of any help because html is automatically generated @Brian

Comment: Try to [explicitly wait for link to be clickable](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the desired element is a dynamic element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.oe_menu_leaf[href*='/web#menu_id=']>span.oe_menu_text"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `text()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='oe_menu_leaf' and starts-with(@href,'/web#menu_id=')]/span[@class='oe_menu_text' and text()='Reoni']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='oe_menu_leaf' and contains(@href,'/web#menu_id=')]/span[@class='oe_menu_text' and normalize-space()='Reoni']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: thank you very much @DabanjanB , example three works, i do not know why the first two do not work, come without a error but no action is done

Comment: @DejanDakovic Well, this observation was expected. The _webpage_ is dynamic. There is a delta difference between the text based _HTML_ and the snapshot of the _HTML_ you have provided. So considering both the _usecases_ either Option 1 & 2 or Option 3 must have worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

## Clicking the button

From Chrome :

Right click "inspect" on the item you are trying to find the xpath.

Right click on the highlighted area on the console.

Go to Copy xpath

```
selectElem=browser.find_element_by_xpath('x-path-here').click()
```

## Reading Values Only

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(innerHTML.encode('utf-8').strip()), 'lxml')
value = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'fxst-calendarpro fxst-table-s1'}).text
```

Comment: But Dejan is using Selenium, which means he may be doing automation that requires interaction with this and other objects.  BeautifulSoup is a great parsing tool, but it's not a web automation tool.

Comment: That's a great point @Bill M. - i'm not sure if he needs web automation, or just values.

Comment: hy,thank you, but I need to click on the item, not just the value @DanielScott

Comment: @Dejan Dakovic No prob :) I've updated my answer. I've had pretty good success selected by x-path over class.

Comment: Getting XPath from browser dev tools is a really bad advice that can hardly solve this issue

Comment: @Andersson You made a great suggestion about trying explicit wait time. Why is it so bad to select using xpath? Would you have preffered I write it as dynamic?

Comment: Because such XPath expressions looks awful :) it's hard to maintain such XPath and you never know which element exactly it suppose to select. Also I see no class duplicates and `NoSuchElementException` means that no elements were found (not even one with required class name). All 3 selectors seem to be OK, so no need to use other selectors